# How to set default editor when using Git in Cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin

I am using the `Git` CLI in `Cygwin` on `Win7`.  I have a problem when I issue a command that requires editor interaction, such as

```
git commit --amend
```

In Cygwin, the command simply hangs and I must do `Ctrl-Z` to get the next prompt.  The commit does not go through.

I tried to set the default editor to `vi`:

```
git config --global core.editor "vi"
```

But that did not work.

In Windows Terminal (DOS-like CLI), it redirects to a vi-like editor fine, i.e. business as usual.  But it doesn't work in Cygwin.  I prefer using Cygwin over Terminal because I was having some other issues in Terminal (wasn't showing which remotes the locals are tracking etc.)

How do I set the default editor when using Git on Cygwin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/638907/134610), I did the following:

```
git config --global core.editor "D:/homex/SFTWR/cygwin/bin/vi.exe"
```

`D:/homex/SFTWR/cygwin` is the location of my `Cygwin` install.  I am still perplexed why it is taking a Windows path when it's running in the Cygwin shell.

Comment: Alternativly you can use the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable.

Comment: I used the cygwin path and it worked for me. My guess would be, cygwin's smart enough to convert your Windows path into a cygwin path.